# chosen select option[chosen-drop] cut off on bootstrap table-responsive

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-chosen

I have problem with chosen select within ng-repeat within bootstrap table, in  chosen-drop option went inside table-responsive below image
[image]

I can achieve this by change CSS

```
.table-responsive{
    overflow:visible !important;
}
```

like below image

[image]

my problem is I don't want to change `overflow:visible` because the table width is  `1700px` so table scrollable is required Is there any options to overcome this?

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp',['localytics.directives']);
    app.controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
      $scope.items=[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3},{id:4}];
      $scope.selectitems=[{id:1,name:"One"}];
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chosen/1.8.3/chosen.jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-chosen-localytics/1.8.0/angular-chosen.js"></script>
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-bordered" style="width:1700px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="a in items">
            <td class="col-md-1">{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td class="col-md-2"><select class="chosen-select input-sm form-control full-width" data-chosen="" data-ng-model="a.id" data-ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in selectitems" required><option value="">Select</option></select></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

codepen working [link](https://codepen.io/kalaiselvan/pen/qxqQYX)

Comment: And overflow:auto; is not an option either?

Comment: @Babydead no its not an option

Comment: Well, in your example I get a scrollbar when I open the select. This behaviour is to be expected since you're using overflow hidden. Unfortunately there is no simple fix for that. This is what overflow hidden will make happen. It hides any overflowing elements, including bootstrap-selects.
**Especially** since these are bootstrap selects, because that means they're just divs within a parent. -- You do realise you can set `overflow-y:visible; overflox-x: auto`?

Comment: @Babydead no, it also not get effect